# Selecting corect node to scrape data with HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: c#, web-scraping, html-agility-pack

I am trying to get data from an html document that look like this

```
<div class="card-body">
    <div class='row'>
        <div class='col-12'>
            <table class='table table-responsive-lg'>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Αριθμός Ε/Κ</th>
                        <th>ΑΚΛΑ - Στίχος</th>
                        <th>Περιγραφή</th>
                        <th>Ημερομηνία</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>TLLU5106835</td>
                        <td>2022037853-158</td>
                        <td>DISCHARGE</td>
                        <td>2022-10-05 22:08:08</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>TLLU5106835</td>
                        <td>2022037853-158</td>
                        <td>X-RAY</td>
                        <td>2022-10-06 08:51:10</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>INVOICE PAID</th>
                        <th colspan="3">Y</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th colspan="4"/>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div> 
</div>
```

So far I was getting the data using the following code

```
HtmlNode[] nodes = doc.DocumentNode
     .SelectNodes("//div[contains(@class,'card-body')]//tr")
     .LastOrDefault()?
     .SelectNodes(".//td")
     .ToArray();

                if (nodes != null)
                {
                    foreach (HtmlNode item in nodes)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(item.InnerHtml);
                        string[] akla = nodes[1].InnerHtml.ToString().Split('-');
                        containerGridView.SetRowCellValue(i, colArithmosAKLA, akla[0]); //AKLA Number
                        containerGridView.SetRowCellValue(i, colStixosAKLA, akla[1]);//AKLA stixos

                        string[] date = nodes[3].InnerHtml.ToString().Split();
                        containerGridView.SetRowCellValue(i, colEtosAKLA, DateTime.Now.Year); //AKLA Year

                       
                        if (akla[0].IsNullOrEmpty())
                        {
                            containerGridView.SetRowCellValue(i, colArithmosAKLA, "NOT LOADED");
                        }
                    }
                    if (containerGridView.GetRowCellValue(i, colArithmosAKLA).IsNull())
                        containerGridView.SetRowCellValue(i, colArithmosAKLA, "NOT LOADED");
                }
```

but they change something in the web page and now I don't get any data.

When it reach the foreach loop it exit the code.

The "nodes" contains this information

> {HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode[0]}

which I don't know if it is correct

The data that I want is the

> 2022037853-158

Comment: Shouldn't it be `.SelectNodes(".//tbody//td")`? (or something like that)

Comment: @DavidG The code was working fine. The HTML document is not only the one I have. It has many elements. I just gave the one that I want to scrape

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

I just removed the //tr from selectedNodes and it worked.

```
 .SelectNodes("//div[contains(@class,'card-body')]")
```

If someone can explain to me what this //tr does so I can understand why removing this worked.

Thanks